# Не согласен с отклонением проверки по ответу

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Есть вот такой "ответ" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746258/186083
Мной (да и не только мной) он был помечен на проверку, но отклонен кем-то из модераторов.

Я считаю, что он не является ответом, а является выражением благодарности на ответ от @user2720882 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711585/186083

> Спасибо тебе, человек с сообщением ниже

прямо указание идет на первоначальный ответ:

> Такая ошибка может возникать при повреждении файла config.ini В нем прописаны пути к необходимым классам и библиотекам.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд (отклонял я), если убрать благодарности из конца ответа - это вполне себе ответ. Даже если он основан на другом ответе в нём есть указание на то, как была решена проблема - `Попробуйте перезалить его с резервной копии`, чего нет в другом ответе.

Да, возможно, следовало бы дополнить другой ответ, не создавая новый. Но лично я не увидел тут большой проблемы.

Если ответ вам совсем не кажется нормальным, то можно проголосовать против - так больше вероятность его удаления.

Comment: В обоих ответах речь о config.ini. В первом ответе однозначно написано **при повреждении файла**. Второй ответ даже если это не Спасибо, то это частный случай первого ответа.

Comment: @Visman, возможно вы правы. Но я вижу 2 неполных ответа. Если бы в ответе, который мы считаем первым было бы упоминание о том, что можно резервной копией заменить, то да - второй ответ, с благодарностями был бы не нужен. Т.е. если один ответ отредактировать, добавив туда это, то второй можно и заминусить и потереть, указав в комментарии к нему, что в другом ответе есть вся необходимая информация. В данный же момент люди, которые придут смотреть ответы при удалении проблемного ответа не увидят как можно проблему решить